# Groovy CliBuilder - Argument value containing spaces

Tags: java, bash, groovy, command-line

I'm using the Groovy CLiBuilder with the following option :

```
    cli.with {
        b longOpt: 'build', args:4, valueSeparator: ",", argName: 'a1,a2,a3,a4', 'This is the description', required: false
    }
```

This works well, I can correctly parse the 4 arguments with the following:

```
    def _a1 = options.bs[0]
    def _a2 = options.bs[1]
    def _a3 = options.bs[2]
    def _a4 = options.bs[3]
```

So far so good .... BUT, if one of my argument's value contains a space ... then it doesn't work anymore. When I do the following call from bash:

```
myScript.sh -b value_a1,value_a2,value a 3,value a 4
```

I end up with following String Array for my values :

```
[valu_a1, value_a2, value, --]
```

But it perfectly works if none of my argument's value contain spaces.

Did anyyone already encoutner this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it using quotes: `-b "value_a1,value_a2,value a 3,value a 4"`

That is how the shell works and not a problem of CliBuilder

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't help. I ended up with the exact same problem, so yes, I believe this is a CliBuilder problem!